# Difference between having \begin{axis} blablabla \end{axis} and \draw[->]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

What is the difference between them? Which one is better for what purposes?

If im writing a paper in mathematical analysis, which should i use?

Comment: Both commands can create axes... But the `axis` environment is more automated and possibly you will have to write less code to have ticks and labels and legends etc. personally I prefer to use the basic `tikz` commands like `\draw` in order to have full flexibility in my generated output and because learning to use `axis` environment needs more memory about its options and the way they should be used to give a non so standard output. In short, `axis` will give automated axes and labels and legends etc... and `\draw` will need much more commands for a simple graph.. Adjusting could inverse this

Comment: If you are willing to read the pgf manual for as many adjustments (on the axes, the `label`s, the `mark`s the `legend`s etc) as possible and could remember all these, `axis` environment would save you from extra coding... If not, a few basic tikz commands like `\draw` could help you to do almost everything but usually with much more code and some (mostly in very special requests) times with less. My point of view is that  keeping my memory somehow empty and available for more important for me things is preferable even if I have to code some more... Coding is fun anyway! Hope that helped.

Comment: Final, I have to add, that if you go for the `\draw` option... Check at least the `\foreach` command as soon as possible before really start creating axes...

Comment: There is no "difference" because internally `axis` uses `\draw[->]...` (unless you suppress the axis lines). Which one you should use depends on what you want to depict. If you want to draw a simple circle, an `axis` might be an overkill, if you want to draw a 3d plot with 3d ordering of surfaces, you may need it badly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no intrinsic difference because internally axis uses `\draw[->]...` (unless you suppress the axis lines). Which one you should use depends on what you want to depict. Here are some thoughts:

1. If you want to draw a simple circle, an axis might be an overkill.
2. If you want to draw a 3d plot with 3d ordering of surfaces, you may need `pgfplots` badly.
3. In general `pgfplots` is particularly useful if you want to plot a function that you can parametrize.
4. On the other hand, if you want to sketch things, plain Ti*k*Z may be more straightforward. It will also compile a bit faster.
5. There is no true distinction because `pgfplots` is based on Ti*k*Z. So if you start working with them, you may want to make yourself familiar with basic Ti*k*Z syntax first.

Comment: I didn't provided an answer and commented instead, because I don't use `pgfplots` often and it was somehow harder for me to give some example (2 or 3) to make clear what I meant... But during writing my comments, I was thinking that you could do what I didn't... since you are expert on both and just a copy paste/adjustment of 2,3 of your answers would make clear the differences... (+1 anyway, but if this is not a duplicate I would be glad to see more from you on this question).

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for the heads up! I actually do not know how to *really* answer this question because the answer will depend very much on the user. Without any concrete example it is very hard to give a meaningful advice, and even with it is hard because if often happens that in the very end someone decides "Oh, and now I'd like to add this thingy." which completely invalidates the choice made previously. One can also use `\draw[->]...` in a tree, in which case I'd most likely would recommend `forest`, or for true 3d stuff `asymptote`.

Comment: You are right, but your answer could be a nice demonstration without giving "your hart" to one or the other solution. (I could not do this but you can due to `pgf` knowledge). For example, you could give two simple plots as a first step (Let's say of `f(x)=x^2,  0<x<3`) with both approaches (that would show how easier `pgfplots` makes it) and then adjust in the same plot with each way the "ticks" (not sure about the word... the lines that shows the values on each axis), ... (nothing on x=0,small on x=0.5, big x=1, small x=1.5, big x=2, small x=2.5). [Just an example -not sure if appropriate-]

Comment: This question is in any case find-able from non advanced `tikz` and `pgfplots` users but from newcomers to this stuff... Sure one really simple and one just somehow more advanced example would help any newcomer to just get an idea from where to start... This is the point of such a question but without advice or plus/minus... Let them see both work. (my example may be is not appropriate but sure you can find an appropriate to demonstrate both of them working)

Comment: @koleygr This site is full of nice examples and the manuals are IMHO very nicely written, much nicer than any answer here could. Any attempt to beat those will IMHO be futile. There exists already a good number of tutorials.

Comment: May be you are right... ok.... just enraptured (if correct word) by the idea. Have a nice night...